# AJAX not updating MySql data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have created this PHP script to update the status of users. I am having some difficulty while running the below code. The code of the page is given below: -

```
    $query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id='$id' ";
    $query_run = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    if($query_run)
    {
        $_SESSION['status'] = "Successfully Deleted";
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['status'] = "Something Went Wrong.!";
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
```

The query here fails to run. The below ajax code sends the data to this page using a POST request

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "code.php",
            data: {
                    'checking_edit_btn': true,
                    'student_id': stud_id,
                      },
            success: function (response) {
            $.each(response, function (key, value) { 
            $('#edit_id').val(value['id']);
            });
            $('#editStudentModal').modal('show');
            };
            });
```

update It's working now, here is the final code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "code.php",
        data: {
               'delete_student': true,
                'student_id': stud_id,
                  },
        success: function (response) {
        $.each(response, function (key, value) { 
        $('#edit_id').val(value['id']);
        });
        $('#editStudentModal').modal('show');
        };
        });
```

Comment: It appears that you are not sending update_student or delete_student as well as several other fields that your PHP code looks for in the Ajax call. Go through the PHP code and list the fields it looks for, then modify your JavaScript code to sent those bits of info. also look at the spelling of those fields to make sure they match up.

Comment: _the error I get is "something went wrong"_  Which one? The first or the second message? Add a number to distingish.

Comment: **Warning!** You are _wide open_ for [SQL injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) attacks! You should use parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using completely unescaped user data directly in your queries like that. _Never ever ever never_ trust user input.

Comment: can u provide me the code

Comment: Use PHP-Xdebug for debugging and then you can run each line of code one by one. I mostly fix these kind of error using that. PHP X-debug extension can be installed on VS code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where you sending 'update_student'/'delete_student'?

try to add to data

```
update_student: true
```

or

```
delete_student: true
```

depends on button

Comment: i am sending the the data to code.php i had gave the code above and please tell me where to put the statement: ['delete_student: true'] and ['update_student: true']

Comment: data: {
                        update_student: true,
                        student_id: 'stud_id'
                    }
or:  
data: {
                        delete_student: true,
                        student_id: 'stud_id'
                    }